# dashes in DTD not validating

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

I have a `DTD` supplied by someone else, and it is not validating when I try to use `XSLT`.  Here is an extract:

```
<!ELEMENT        vehicle                        - -        (#PCDATA | left | centre | right)* 
                                                -(vehicle |
                                                   date |
                                                   title |
                                                   price |
                                                   id |
                                                   code |
                                                   ref |
                                                  %changeref
                                                )>
```

The parser has a problem with the two dashes on the first line.  Is this an old way of doing `DTDs` that the parser has a problem with?

The `DTD` is quite big and these dashes are all the way through the definitions.  Is there something I can do to make it validate?

Comment: The dash on the second line is also SGML specific. That’s an exclusion (those elements aren’t allowed as descendants at any level). If that was a + it would be an inclusion (those elements would be allowed as descendants at any level) which is also only allowed in an SGML DTD.

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please accept an answer.  If not, please follow-up to state what else you need to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That DTD is for SGML, not XML.

The extra `- -` are for tag minimization, which XML does not support.  You'll have to remove those if you want to use the DTD for XML.

### See also

- [Comparison of SGML and XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml.html)
- [Converting an SGML DTD to XML](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/dtd/)